# rails: using a class defined in another module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, methods, scope

I am getting the following error, when I try to run my application:

```
uninitialized constant RegistrationsController::User_serial
```

In my config/application.rb, I have:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

In my registrations_controller.rb, I have the following:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  ........

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    user_serial_local = User_serial.new #initialize class defined in lib/my_tools.rb
    date_time_local = Date_formatter.new
    ......
```

In lib/my_tools.rb, I define some classes:

```
class User_serial
  def self.calculate(first,last)
    first_3 = first[0..2]
    last_4 = last[0..3]
    time = Time.now.to_i
    return first_3 + last_4 + time.to_s
  end 
end

class Date_formatter
  def self.datetime
    return Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  end
end
```

There are a lot of references to overriding a class, and instructions on how to insure that anything placed in the lib folder is included (followed in my code). Why am I getting the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rails' magic loading to work it needs to be able to find the file a class/module is defined in based only on the class name.

This in turn means sticking to rails' naming conventions and putting things where rails expects: UserSerial should be defined in user_serial.rb. You might be able to get User_serial to work as a class name but rails will never look in my_tools.rb for that class.

Comment: Note the modifications I made to config/application.rb telling it to autoload everything in the lib folder. This is from the Rails online docs, and some answers I found on StavkOverflow. Are you saying that this is not correct?

Comment: This adds any subfolder in there to the list of places rails would search for user_serial.rb. In production rails will actually load all those files when the app boots, but in development they are only on demand.

Comment: So, where would I put UserSerial? in helpers/registrations_helper.rb or in helpers/user_serial.rb?

Comment: Rails would expect it to be in user_serial.rb in any of the folders in its autoload path (eg lib). helpers would probably work but normally you only put view helpers there

Comment: The following worked:

In my_tools.rb declare the classes/methods you will be using and put that in the lib folder, and then in registrations_controller.rb, add the following:

    require 'my_tools.rb'

Comment: If you do that I don't think rails will pickup changes to that code without restarting the app